# How to get list of parquet file names from a directory in Azure datalake in pyspark?

Tags: azure, pyspark, parquet, azure-synapse, data-lake

I want to get a list of all parquet file names from a directory in Azure datalake in Pyspark.
The long file names starting with 'part-'

How to achieve this?

Comment: Hello @Sparc , you can use os library like: files = os.listdir(path), with path : the path to the folder containing parquets files.  In files  you will have the list all files, after that you can filter the list by keeping only those whom start by 'part'

Comment: Hi @MerciDieuKIMPOLO, it's giving me error as no such file or directory. How do I solve this?

Comment: Hi @samkart, that does not work. I want to run the code from Azure synapse notebook using Pyspark to get the names of the parquet files from a directory where the files are in datalake.

Comment: please add the platform tag(s) for better reach and understanding

Comment: Hi @samkart, apologies. I did tag now. Please can you advice. Thank you

Comment: it has a [document on file management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python)

Comment: Hello @Sparc, sorry for the delay can you add the error in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and got below results.

These are my parquet files in ADLS container.

[image]

To get these files in synapse first **mount the ADLS to synapse using ADLS linked service**.

After mounting, use the below code to get the parquet files that starts with `part`.

```
files_list=mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://<container_name>@<storageaccount_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/")
print("Total files list : ",files_list)
flist=[]
for i in  range(0,len(files_list)):
    if(files_list[i].name.startswith('part')):
        flist.append(files_list[i].path)
print("\n  \n File paths that starts with part",flist)
```

**My Execution for your reference:**

[image]

If you want to read all files you can just use wild card path `part*` in the file path like this.

```
df=spark.read.parquet("abfss://<container_name><storageaccount_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/part*.parquet")
```

[image]